# How can I add a .js file to an assembly in an ASP.NET project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms, .net-assembly

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms project in VS 2013 and I need a function to clear the contents of all text boxes on a button click.  I want to obviously do this client side so need javascript.  I can't find this function in any of the preinstalled js files or jquery or bootstrap etc, so I need to create my own.
Fine.  So I've created the js file with the function in it.

I added a reference in the _references.js file and I have added a script reference in my master page

However, when I run I get an error:
Assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not contain a Web resource with name 'CustomerDetails.js'.

I don't have the option to add to an assembly in the properties of customerdetails.js (as this is a webforms project).

Can anyone tell me how to add to / create an assembly to reference this js file?!!

Muchos Gracias

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add file to *assembly*, you should add it to [resource file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296240(v=vs.95).aspx). But is it real need to embed script to the resource of assembly? Since your application uses asp.net you can just copy this script to specified folder and [configure your script manager](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/21/asp-net-4-5-scriptmanager-improvements-in-webforms.aspx) to handle it.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm sure I'm not getting something here, but I have added the script to the specified folder, and have configured the script manager (in my master page, but as it isn't part of an assembly, it won't run.   And I can't add to a resource file as I don't have the option.